# variables in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, variables

I am getting a particular value by using

```
<xsl:value-of select="@date" />
```

and i want to store this value as a variable say 'd'
How can i do this and also tell me how can i use that caribale back in my template.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Here's one I've been bitten by often: storing the results of boolean expressions in variables won't work the way you might expect. <variable name="x" select="1=2"/> will store the string "false" in x, and "false" is, of course, TRUE because it's a non-empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<xsl:variable name="d" select="@date" />
<xsl:value-of select="$d" />
```

Looking through [the basics](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) might be worthwhile. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

That would be

```
<xsl:variable name="date" select="@date" />
```

to declare a symbol referencing the node `@date`.

To use it later on you can reference that symbol by prefixing the name with `$`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$date" />
```

Note that once the symbol is declared you cannot change its value in XSLT.

Comment: @divo: Casual nitpicking: You're not declaring a symbol with the *value of* @date, but rather one with a *reference to* the node.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak, my mistake. That's actually quite a difference.